# Letter-Sending probability problem

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

Here is another question from the book of V. Rohatgi and A. Saleh. I would like to ask help again. Here it goes:

Consider a town with $N$ people. A person sends two letters to two separate people, each of whom is asked to repeat the procedure. Thus for each letter received, two letters are sent out to separate persons chosen at random (irrespective of what happened in the past). What is the probability that in the first $n$ stages the person who started the chain letter game will not receive a letter?

I am thinking of solving this through complementation, i.e. what I have so far is that for $n=1$, $$P\{\text{the person who started the chain letter game will receive a letter}\}=0$$ for $n=2$,  $$P\{\text{the person who started the chain letter game will receive a letter from the 1st sender}\}$$  $$=P\{\text{the person who started the chain letter game will receive a letter from the 2nd sender}\}$$ $$=\frac{_{N-2}C_1}{_{N-1}C_2}$$ $$P\{\text{the person who started the chain letter game will receive letters from both 2nd senders}\}$$ $$=\left(\frac{_{N-2}C_1}{_{N-1}C_2}\right)^2$$ Then I would simply calculate the probability of the union of the elementary events, then continue for each $n$. Now, I find it too tedious and I am not so sure if this correct. Can anyone help please? Thanks.

Comment: Complementation only helps with half the problems in the world. At most. Maybe you should try doing it without complementation.

Comment: I would also appreciate if anyone can help me do this without using complementation. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let stage $k=0$ denote the person who started the chain (say A) sending out the first two letters to two different people.  I assume you are asking for the probability that after stage $k=n$, A does not receive a letter.

Further, as per the problem statements, even if a person receives $m>1$ letters in a stage or across stages, all that is taken care of is that each letter results in a pair of letters going out to two separate people, irrespective of whether they were recipients of other letters by the same sender.

In this situation, we worry only about how many such letter pairs are sent across stages $k=1,2, ...n$.  This is $L = 2+4+... 2^n = 2(2^n-1)$.

Each time a letter is received, there are $(N-1)(N-2)$ ways to select two separate people to send a letter pair to.  If A is not to be one of them, this choice reduces to $(N-2)(N-3)$.  Hence the probability for A not receiving a letter at this time is
$p = \dfrac{(N-2)(N-3)}{(N-1)(N-2)} = \dfrac{N-3}{N-1}$.

As this event occurs independently $L$ times, the total probability is $p^L = \left(  \dfrac{N-3}{N-1}\right)^{2(2^n-1)}$.

Comment: Thanks @Macavity. The solution is well explained. I very much appreciate it.

Comment: I have to ask, I think the total number of letters to be sent out which must be accounted for must $L-2$ instead of the original $L$, since the first $2$ letters were initially sent by A, hence has probability $0$ of reaching A. Am I correct on this? Thanks.

Comment: The first letter pair being sent out is already not being counted in L, that is why we start counting from 2 people sending out letter pairs. Test it out for some low values of n and see.

Comment: Actually, I did check them out @Macavity. So I think you have to subtract $2$ from the original $L$ you had. Since the first stage, I think, identifies the first $2$ letters sent out, hence we should start the count at $4$; thus, $$4+8+...+2^n=4\left(2^{n-1}-1\right)$$ "independent" letters are accounted for. Please verify if you can, sir. Thanks.

Comment: For $n=1$, we have A sending out two letters for $k=0$ and their recipients sending out two each for $k=n=1$.  So exactly **two** events with probability $p$ each, $L=2 = 2(2^1-1)$.

Comment: Ah okay. Now I think our perspectives differed in the sense that you considered the stage that A sends out two letters as stage 0, while I thought of having it as stage 1. Anyways, you're idea was great. It was a lot of help. Thanks

Comment: Not a problem, I suspected there could be ambiguity in how $n$ is defined, which is why my assumption was stated in the start.

Answer (score 1):

**hint:** use the independence of events. How many letters are sent out by not 1?

For each letter that is sent out by not 1, What is the probability that 1 will not receive this letter?